# Draw a MKCircleRenderer on MKMapSnapshotter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a `MKCircleRenderer` in a `MKMapSnapshotter`.

So what I need:
[image]

So what I have:
[image]

My code:

```
+ (void)renderMapRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region
               withSize:(CGSize)size
             annotation:(MKAnnotationView *)annotation
         circleRenderer:(MKCircleRenderer *)circleRenderer
             completion:(CMMapViewRendererCallback)block
{
    MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [MKMapSnapshotOptions new];
    options.region = region;
    options.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    options.size = size;

    MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];

    [snapshotter startWithQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
              completionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {

                  if (error) {
                      block(nil, error);
                      return;
                  }

                  UIImage *image = snapshot.image;

                  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, image.scale);
                  {
                      [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
                      CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

                      if (circleRenderer.path) {
                          [circleRenderer applyFillPropertiesToContext:c atZoomScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
                          CGContextAddPath(c, circleRenderer.path);
                          CGContextFillPath(c);
                      }

                      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                      CGPoint point = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:annotation.annotation.coordinate];
                      if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
                          point.x = point.x + annotation.centerOffset.x - (annotation.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
                          point.y = point.y + annotation.centerOffset.y - (annotation.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
                          [annotation.image drawAtPoint:point];
                      }

                      UIImage *compositeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                      block(compositeImage,nil);
                  }

                  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

              }];
}
```

My annotation is correct, but the `MKCircleRenderer` is drawn in a wrong coordinate.

**UPDATE 1**

After some tryings. I hade only one problem: correct radius size. My circle has 15meters radius value. But when I print on map has a 119 (I dont know about the unit)

```
private func renderMap(#placemark: CLPlacemark?, annotationView: MKAnnotationView) {
        self.tempPlaceMark = placemark
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotationView.annotation.coordinate, 5000, 5000)
        let circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: annotationView.annotation.coordinate, radius: radius!)
        var render = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)
        render.fillColor = Color.YellowColor

        CMMapViewRenderer.renderMapRegion(region, withSize: self.mapView.frame.size, annotation: annotationView, circleRenderer: render) { (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if error == nil {
                    self.tempCoordinate = annotationView.annotation.coordinate
                    self.tempSnapshotImage = image
                }
                self.dismissProgress()
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Based on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8288467/846780

```
CGPoint circlePoint = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:annotation.annotation.coordinate];
CGRect boundingRect = [circleRenderer rectForMapRect:circleRenderer.circle.boundingMapRect];
CGFloat radius = boundingRect.size.width / 2;
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, circleRenderer.fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, circleRenderer.fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(c, YES);
CGContextAddArc(c, circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y, radius, 0, 2 * M_PI, true);
CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFill);
```

Comment: It looks like your `circleRenderer` is being drawn using map coordinates and is not being converted to the snapshot's point coord.

Comment: I think that is true, but how can I draw circleRenderer in a specific position?

Comment: you could capture your circle as a new image (context) and place it using the point coord.

Comment: BTW, rather than putting your working solutions in your question, you might [post your own answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), as strange as that seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to draw this `MKCircle` yourself, converting the `center` and `radius` properties into coordinates within the view. This renders the circle within the current context (which I've used for adding `MKCircle` overlays to a snapshot image):

```
// use whatever colors you want

[[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
[[[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7] setFill];

// in my code, I'm iterating through the `overlays` objects, so I test to 
// see if it's a circle and cast appropriately

if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [(MKCircle *)overlay coordinate];
    CGPoint center = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:coordinate];
    CLLocationDistance radiusInMeters = [(MKCircle *)overlay radius];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, radiusInMeters, 0);
    CGRect rect = [self.mapView convertRegion:region toRectToView:self.mapView];
    CGFloat radiusInPoints = rect.size.height;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radiusInPoints startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:TRUE];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([path bounds], CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))) {
        [path stroke];
        [path fill];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no self.mapView instance inside this class. How can I get de "rect"?

Comment: Your `rectForMapRect` approach accomplishes the same thing. Two ways of skinning the cat. The only question then is whether you want to use CoreGraphics or `UIBezierPath`. BTW, neither of our two approaches work well if the camera isn't looking straight down (though the `rectForMapRect` might get you closer). I really hate this horrible "you have to draw your own annotations and overlays" silliness.

Comment: The only difficult is translate radius circle to the image. Both approaches are confusing for me to accomplish it .

Comment: How can convert circleRenderer.circle.radius?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to convert that. You're calculating radius from `boundingRect`. That's fine. You're calculating the center and radius of the arc to be drawn differently than me, but we generate the same values, I suspect, and your approach is fine (and if you don't have the map view, it's probably even better). So don't sweat that. The only question is, having calculated the center and the radius, whether you want to draw the circle with Core Graphics or just `stroke`/`fill` the `UIBezierPath`. Either is fine.

Comment: My UPDATE1 I've created a MKCircle with 15 meters of radius. How we can see... is too different